# Order by position in product collection

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.4

I'm trying to order products by position in category

```
public function __getProductCollection($category_id_array) {

    $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $collection->addCategoriesFilter(['in' => $category_id_array]);
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH);
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('status', \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
    //$collection->addAttributeToSort('position');
    $collection->setOrder('position','ASC');
    

    return $collection;
}
```

I got this error

```
 Unknown column 'cat_index_position' in 'order clause'
```

I tried also

```
$collection->setOrder('cat_index_position','ASC');

$collection->setOrder('cat_index.position','ASC');
```

But the ordering is not working

PS: i'm using Magento 2.2.4

Comment: Try `$collection->getSelect()->reset(Zend_Db_Select::ORDER)->order('position', 'ASC');` if it helps!

Comment: @Bhaumik1987 i think position doesn't exist on the product collection i solved the problem, you can see my solution below

Comment: @Bhaumik1987 I got this error Uncaught Error: Class 'Wetag\CarouselNamePlate\Block\Widget\Zend_Db_Select' not found

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem

i added a class attribute _categoryFactory and used it in constructor

```
public function __construct(
\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context
,\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory) {
    parent::__construct(
            $context, $data
    );
    $this->_categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
}



public function __getProductCollection($category_id) {

    $products = $this->_categoryFactory->create()->load($category_id)->getProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->setOrder('cat_index_position','ASC');
    return $products;
}
```